# Set future expiry date as default value in sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sqlite, orm, sequelize.js

I'm saving logintokens with a lifetime of 365 days using the following sequelize beforeCreate Hook:

```js
let hooks = {
    setExpires: (instance, options, done) => {
        if(instance.get('expires')) {
            return done();
        }
        instance.set('expires', Sequelize.literal('NOW() + INTERVAL 1 YEAR'));
        return done();
    }
};

Logintoken.beforeCreate(hooks.setExpires);
Logintoken.beforeBulkCreate(hooks.setExpires);
```

It works great as long as I use MySQL. Other dialects such as SQLite don't understand `NOW() + INTERVAL 1 YEAR`, which is bad. Is there a built-in cross-dialect way to achieve what I am trying to do here?

I've already studied the docs, googled like hell and even had a look at the source code but couldn't find anything that looks like date calculation.

Comment: Since you are using beforeCreate, why not set the expires via javascript instead of sql?

Comment: That's too obvious ;)
`instance.set('expires', moment().add(365, 'days'));` seems to work fine. Thank you ;)

Comment: Worked for me too, just have to make sure you define the field on the model. I used type: sequels.DATE and defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW

Comment: @Jona can you more describe ? i have 1 field mysql (coulmn_schedule) , its timestamp then i would make it expired when 1x24 hours from 1 field mysql ( column_schedule )